# codeigniter pagination with dynamic url structure

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

In my codeigniter app i have an article module, which has three categories,

primary category
secondary category
tertiary category
list of articles

Now the first page shows an accordion with the heirarchy above except the list of articles, the user can click on expand or click on a category name directly.

So if a user clicks on primary category name all the articles will be listed paginated based on codeigniter's inbuilt pagination library.

Likewise if a tertiary category is clicked articles in that alone will be listed. The problem is all the articles listing is handled by a single function and hence i have a route like this.

```
$route['article/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "articles/articles/show_article/$4";
$route['article/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "articles/articles/find_type/$3";
$route['article/(:any)/(:any)'] = "articles/articles/find_type/$2";
$route['article/(:any)'] = "articles/articles/find_type/$1";
```

and my find_type method is

```
function find_type($str)
    {
        $rawstr = $str;
        $str = deurl($str);
        $ch = 1;
        $id = 0;
        $query = $this->db->get_where("articles_primary",array("primary_name"=>$str));
        if($query->num_rows==1) {
          $ch = 1;
          $id = $query->row('id');
        }
        $query = $this->db->get_where("articles_secondary",array("secondary_name"=>$str));
        if($query->num_rows==1) {
          $ch = 2;
          $id = $query->row('id');
        }
        $query = $this->db->get_where("articles_tertiary",array("tertiary_name"=>$str));
        if($query->num_rows==1) {
          $ch = 3;
          $id = $query->row('id');
        }
        $query = $this->db->get_where("articles_list",array("url_title"=>$rawstr));
        if($query->num_rows==1) {
          $ch = 4;
        }
        switch ($ch)
        {
            case 1:
              $this->show_articles_list($id,"primary",$rawstr);
              break;
            case 2:
              $this->show_articles_list($id,"secondary",$rawstr);
              break;
            case 3:
              $this->show_articles_list($id,"tertiary",$rawstr);
              break;
            case 4:
              $this->show_article($rawstr);
              break;
        }
    }
```

and finally my list articles is

```
function show_articles_list($id,$tbl,$rawstr)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get_where("articles_list",array($tbl."_id"=>$id));

        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config['base_url'] = current_url();
        $config['total_rows'] = $query->num_rows;
        $config['per_page'] = 9;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $page = $this->uri->segment(3);

        if($page=="") { $page = 0; }
        $this->db->limit(9,$page);
        $data["query"] = $this->db->get_where("articles_list",array($tbl."_id"=>$id));

        $this->template->write_view('maincontent', 'articles/articles_list',$data);
        //$this->template->write_view('subcontent', 'articles/related_articles',$data);
        $this->template->write("title","Laws",true);
        $this->template->write_view('rightcontent','general/include/query_document_tab');
        $this->template->render();
    }
```

as you can see the routes are based on uri segments and hence the pagination is not working. Is there anyway i can tweak the pagination to work with the current setup i have?

Answer (score 0):

How about adding another parameter to the functions and changing the routes file accordingly:

```
function find_type($str, $page=0){
...
$this->show_articles_list($id,"primary",$rawstr, $page);
etc...
...
}

function show_articles_list($id,$tbl,$rawstr,$page)...
```

Routes:

```
$route['article/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "articles/articles/show_article/$4/4";
$route['article/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "articles/articles/find_type/$3/3";
$route['article/(:any)/(:any)'] = "articles/articles/find_type/$2/2";
$route['article/(:any)'] = "articles/articles/find_type/$1/1";
```

You'd use that parameter to denote the uri segment for pagination.

OR

You can just use [$this->uri->total_segments()](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html).